# 心身を病んでいるが兵団から立ち退くことができないのだ

Tags: translation

I have some doubts about the meaning of this sentence and in particular about the verb 立ち退く and the expression 心身を病んでいる.

This is the complete sentence.

> 心身を病んでいるが兵団から立ち退くことができないのだ.

心身を病んでいる

Does this mean: to be ill in mind and body?

兵団から立ち退くことができないのだ

I think it means: Is impossible to leave (?) the army.

Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right on all counts. 心身を病む means, as you understood, to be ill in mind and body. The suggestion here is that the person is under considerable duress that is taking a toll both mentally and physically, and we can intuit that this is a result of being in the military.

立ち退く is to "leave" in the sense of packing up and getting out of there. Removing yourself from that location. Moving from one place to another, in its simplest terms. In this situation it's just "leaving the military."

However I think it might be more accurate to say "I cannot leave" rather than "it's impossible."